# Subtracting two strings is giving wrong values in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s1 = "abc";
    string s2 = "xyz";

    cout << s2.compare(s1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Simple program in which I am just comparing two string and print the return value of the string::compare function.

```
Output:
1
```

The actual output for this program is `23`.
This similar thing is happening with the ASCII characters.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "a" - "A" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting after running the above code is:-

```
Output:
-2
```

But the output I was expecting is `32`. I don't know what's the problem and why I am getting wrong output.

Comment: *"The actual output for this program"* should be *"The expected output for this program"*

Answer (score 3):

The output of `std::string::compare()` is according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare):

> #### Return value
>
> negative value if *this appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
>
> zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
>
> positive value if *this appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order

`s2` is lexicographically later than `s1`, so `compare` returns a positive value, exactly as expected.

---

`"a" - "A"` is Undefined Behaviour. You are subtracting value of two pointers that do not point to the same array. Any output would be valid, as well as no output, crash, or [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

I suppose you wanted to subtract numeric values of characters, which would in fact give `32` (provided that your compiler is using an ASCII-compliant enconding):

```
'a' - 'A'
```

Answer (score 3):

The return value of [`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) is:

> negative value if `*this` appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
> zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
> positive value if `*this` appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order

As you see, it is only defined as "negative / zero / positive" and the "negative" and "positive" values need not be `-1` and `1`.

`"a"` and `"A"` are *string literals*, which represents arrays. Arrays in expressions are automatically converted to pointers pointing at the first elements of them (some exception exists) and substraction of pointers will result in an integer representing the first pointer is how many elements from the second one.

What you wanted to use should be *character constants*, which are surrounded by `'` instead of `"`.

```
    cout << 'a' - 'A' << endl;
```

Alternatively, you can get the first elements of the arrays using subscripting operators.

```
    cout << "a"[0] - "A"[0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns a positive or negative number or `0`, it may return `1`, `-1` and `0` but doesn't have to.

`"a" - "A"` is performing pointer arithmetic on two unrelated pointers so has undefined behaviour. The behaviour you are seeing is probably that the compiler has laid out your constants in memory as `"a\0A\0"` so your constants are 2 bytes apart giving a result of `-2`.